# Iterating over A dict to access a specific key value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts ('sortings') that I am trying to iterate through to access a values in one specific key of each dict. My code keeps saying that there is a key error for the desired value in the dict. If I print inside the for loop, it prints with the values entered but once I exit the for loop it says there is a key error.

```
 for i in range(sort_len):
    sentence = sortings[i]['content']
    containing_messages.append(sentence)
    print(containing_messages)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: Please give the full error stack

Comment: Why do `range(sort_len)` rather than just iterating over the `sortings` dict itself?

Comment: @match actually, we're both off here. You're saying iterate the dict and I've come up with an excuse for them. They have a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for my understanding of the question. I would require the given input and expected output to provide a better answer.

```
list_of_dicts = [{'keya':'value1_1','keyb':'value2_1','keyc':'value3_1'},
                 {'keya':'value1_2','keyb':'value2_2','keyc':'value3_2'},
                 {'keya':'value1_3','keyb':'value2_3','keyc':'value3_3'}]

list_of_key_values = [my_dict['keyb'] for my_dict in list_of_dicts]

print list_of_key_values
```